# In JVM Instructions, some are of different prefixes but their functions are quite similar. Do we really need them all? If Yes, why?

Tags: java, jvm, java-bytecode-asm

> ***For add*** : iadd/ladd/fadd/dadd, 
>   ***For sub*** : isub/lsub/fsub/dsub,
>   ***For mul*** : imul/lmul/fmul/dmul
>   ***For div*** : idiv/ldiv/fdiv/ddiv
>   ***For rem*** : irem/lrem/frem/drem
>   ***Fro neg*** : ineg/lneg/fneg/dneg...

1. Can we only use only one instruction, *e.g.* **add**, to replace all the add instructions?
2. If the answer of Q1 is true, will this get better performance than current solutions?
3. If Q1 is false, why?

Comment: "quite similar" is quite different from "exactly the same". If all these instructions did the same thing, do you really think they would all exist?

Comment: This is just nomenclature. Java chose to have explicitly different names for what could otherwise be "overloads" of the same name for different argument types. In essence they *are* distinct instructions, whether they share a mnemonic or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like in real machines, you can't have the same instruction for negating a double or an int. These instructions work really different on the bit-level, and are only the same on a sufficiently high abstraction level (i.e. negate a number).

This is why we have higher level languages to abstract away uninteresting machine details. But in an assembly language, the distinction is essential.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1: Can we only use only one instruction, e.g. add to implements all the add instructions?

No.  They are defined to do different things.  Similar, but different.

> If Q1 is false, why?

Because that is the way they defined it.  The bytecode instruction set was designed to be compact, simple to code generate, and capable of expressing Java semantics.  The instruction set meets those goals ... well enough.

The JVM bytecode instruction set was also designed to be stable; i.e. to allow Java code that was compiled to bytecodes 20+ years ago to still be executable on a current JVM.  Changes to the instruction set that break compatibility are anathema: they won't happen.